# How does MySQL store timestamps internally?

Tags: sql, mysql, types, timestamp

How does MySQL store timestamps internally?  Is it an int, or a string or something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html):

TIMESTAMP: A four-byte integer representing seconds UTC since the epoch ('1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC)

Answer (score 2):

32bit integer

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe it uses a UNIX timestamp, which is an integer representing the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch: Jan 01 1970

Answer (score 1):

All Date, Time, Datetime, Timestamp are stored as Integers internally but Different Datatypes has Different Integers Values Like

**YEAR**: A one-byte integer

**DATE**: A three-byte integer packed as YYYY×16×32 + MM×32 + DD

**TIME**: A three-byte integer packed as DD×24×3600 + HH×3600 + MM×60 + SS

**TIMESTAMP**: A four-byte integer representing seconds UTC since the epoch ('1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC)

**DATETIME**: Eight bytes: A four-byte integer for date packed as YYYY×10000 + MM×100 + DD and a four-byte integer for time packed as HH×10000 + MM×100 + SS

Reference: [Data Time Explanatory MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html)